# how to write XSLT file for this XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<signatures status="Started">
  <file path="/home/aaa/bbb" size="707" />
  <file path="/home/aaa/bbb" size="707" />
  <file path="/home/aaa/bbb" size="706" />
  <file path="/home" size="706" />
</signatures>
```

I don't know much about XSLT, i want to convert this XML file into XSLT.

i tried this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    Path,Size
    <xsl:for-each select="//signatures">
      <xsl:for-each select="file">
        <xsl:value-of select="@path"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@size"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but i am not getting any value

Comment: See transform at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWRApp/1 it gives output.

Comment: Thanks , I had problem with xml file , i was not giving space between path and size